# Cross Domain Collect Tracking with SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a Best Practice for Cross Domain Collect Tracking in the SFMC? We work in one business unit. The website portfolio consists of corporate website and various marketing "product" websites. All websites have a different information architecture. The collected data should allow a segmentation by visited website + interaction.

My idea is to place the base tracking code on all websites and record the respective domain as a "category", e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);       
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "category" : "www.site1.com" }]);  
</script>
```

Visited product information on the respective pages, could then be tracked with "Items", e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);       
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "PRODUCT1" }]);   
</script>
```

Does anyone have experience with Cross Domain Collect Tracking? Is there a proposal or best practice?

Many Thanks!